# Building normal filters around a stationary set

Tags: set-theory, filters, infinitary-combinatorics

Recently I've been looking at connections between Laver functions on large cardinals and diamonds. While $\diamondsuit$-like principles tend to readily generalize to Laver function-like concepts, I've run into a problem when going the other way.

Let $S\subseteq \omega_1$ be stationary (you can replace $\omega_1$ with a regular $\kappa$ everywhere). Is there a normal uniform $\sigma$-complete filter on $\omega_1$ containing $S$? In particular, is the filter generated by $S$ together with the club filter normal?

---

After hot_queen resolved my confusion in the comments, I decided to extend the question a bit to try to make it slightly less trivial.

Suppose we have $\omega_1$ many stationary sets $S_\alpha\subseteq \omega_1$ such that any countably many of them have stationary intersection. Is there now a normal uniform $\sigma$-complete filter containing all of the $S_\alpha$? Is the $\sigma$-complete filter generated by the $S_\alpha$ and the club filter normal?

Comment: Do you assume certain $\lozenge(S)$ or some other combinatorial principle to hold?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In general, no, but if you can use it to get a conditional result, that would be interesting for the applications.

Comment: Yes. Normality follows from the usual push down lemma.

Comment: @hot_queen Can you elaborate? Fodor's lemma will give me some stationary set but why is that set generated by $S$ and a club?

Comment: Let I be the non stationary ideal restricted to S (so I is the dual of the filter generated by adding S to the club filter). To show that I is normal, you need to show that every regressive function on any I positive set is constant on some I positive subset. But this is precisely the push down lemma.

Comment: @hot_queen I think I may have been unclear. What I mean by normal filter is that any regressive function on an I-full measure set is constant on an I-full measure set; or equivalently, that the filter itself is closed under diagonal intersections. I don't think your argument gives this.

Comment: Although a normal filter is closed under diagonal intersection, it is not true that any regressive function is constant on a set in the filter so your equivalent thing is false. What is true is this: A filter is closed under diagonal intersection iff the dual ideal satisfies the push down lemma; i.e., every regressive function on any I positive set is constant on some I positive subset You cannot replace I positive by I full here because there are disjoint stationary sets.

Comment: @hot_queen You're right! I was completely confused. Thank you. If you're interested I've extended the question a bit to maybe make it not as trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes.  For any normal ideal $I$ on any kind of set $Z$ for which normality makes sense, $I \restriction S =_{df} \{ A \subseteq Z : A \cap S \in I \}$ is normal.  hot_queen justified this in the comments.

The answer to the second question is no.  To see this, we use the fact that for any sequence of stationary sets $\{ A_\alpha : \alpha < \omega_1\}$, the diagonal union of this sequence is the **least upper bound** of this collection.  Using this, we can find a partition of $\omega_1$ into $\{ A_\alpha : \alpha < \omega_1 \}$ many stationary sets such that this forms a maximal antichain in the algebra $\mathcal{P}(\omega_1)/NS$, i.e. every stationary $S$ has stationary intersection with one of them.

Now let $S_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta \geq \alpha} A_\beta$.  Any countable subset of the $S_\alpha$'s has stationary intersection, and they generate a countably complete filter when taken together with the club filter.

However they do not generate a normal filter, because each $A_\alpha$ is in the dual ideal.  The diagonal union of the $A_\alpha$'s contains a club because they form a maximal antichain.

Comment: This looks great. Just to be sure, to build the $A_\alpha$, you take a partition of $\omega_1$ into $\omega_1$ many stationary sets and, if necessary, throw in the complement of their diagonal union to make it maximal. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you very much.